# Show that $2\sin\left(3x\right)+6\cos\left(5x\right)$ has infinitely many zeros.

Tags: real-analysis

$$\text{WTS }\exists^\infty x\in\mathbb{R},s.t. 2\sin\left(3x\right)+6\cos\left(5x\right)=0$$

Rough work $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\sin(n\pi)=0\wedge\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$$

$$\Rightarrow \forall n\pi\in\mathbb{R},2\sin(3n\pi)=0$$

$$\wedge6\cos(5n\pi)=6(-1)^{5n}$$

Proof.

Let $f:\mathbb{R\to\mathbb{R}},s.t.f(x)=2\sin\left(3x\right)+6\cos\left(5x\right)$

And $f$ is continuous

Let $a_n=n\pi,S:=\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, then

$$\forall i\in\mathbb{N},x_i\in S$$

$$f(x_i)=6\wedge f(x_{i+1})=-6$$

$$\vee f(x_i)=-6\wedge f(x_{i+1})=6$$

$$\overset{\text{IVT}}\implies\forall i\in\mathbb{N,}\exists c_i\in\mathbb{R},s.t.\min(f(x_i),f(x_{i+1}))<c_i<\max(f(x_i),f(x_{i+1}))$$

$$\Rightarrow\forall k\in\mathbb{N}, c\in \{c_1,\dots,c_k\},2\sin\left(3c\right)+6\cos\left(5c\right)=0$$

$$\Rightarrow\forall k\in\mathbb{N},\exists^{\ge k}c,2\sin\left(3c\right)+6\cos\left(5c\right)=0$$

$$\Rightarrow \exists^\infty c\in\mathbb{R},s.t. 2\sin\left(3c\right)+6\cos\left(5c\right)=0\tag*{$\square$}$$

---

$\dots$ Is my proof correct ? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Also please tell me if there is a better method to prove it.

Thanks for your help.

---

Update:

here is some defs. for $\exists^{\ge n}$ and $\exists^\infty$

Def.

$\text{Let n $\in\mathbb{N}$, then }\exists^{\ge n}x,p(x) \text{ if and only if :(exists at least n)}$
$$\exists x_1\dots x_n \text{ s.t.}\underbrace{(p(x_1)\wedge\dots\wedge p(x_n))}_{\text{$x_1\dots x_n$ satisfy $p$}}
\wedge\underbrace{(x_1\neq x_2\dots x_1\neq x_n)\wedge\dots\wedge(x_{n-1}\neq x_n)}_{\text{$x_1\dots x_n$ are distinct}}$$ 
$$\Leftrightarrow\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\exists}} x_i,(\bigwedge_{i=1}^np(x_i))\wedge(\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-1}(\bigwedge_{j=i+1}^nx_i\neq x_j))$$

$\exists^{\infty}x,p(x)$ if and only if:(exists infinitely many) $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists^{\ge n}x,p(x)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\exists}} x_i,(\bigwedge_{i=1}^np(x_i))\wedge(\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n-1}(\bigwedge_{j=i+1}^nx_i\neq x_j))$$

Comment: What do $\exists^\infty$ and $\exists^{\ge k}$ mean?

Comment: Here's one suggestion : write in sentences and try to avoid the logical symbols.

Comment: I think the slickest way would be to establish the existence of one root with the IVT, then use the fact that $f(x+ 2\pi) = f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @TheoBendit I think that's what the OP did.  It's just too blinking difficult to parse so it's really difficult to tell.

Comment: Going to second the notion that you write in sentences.  This could have been written in three choice sentence.  As it is, it is nearly impenetrable.

Comment: No offence to the OP but this is one of my pet peeves in math - when people overuse symbolic logic in a topic other than symbolic logic. This question could've been stated more simply and clearly in plain English. There's no need to make a simple question in analysis look like an excerpt from Russell's Principia Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2\sin (3x) + 6\cos(5x)$ is the sum of two periodic functions of period $2\pi,$ making it a function with period $2\pi$

You only need to show that one zero exists.

$|2\sin 3x| \le 2$

As there are values of $x$ such that $6\cos 5x > 2$ and values where $6\cos 5x < 2$ and sine and cosine are continuous functions, there must be a zero in between (by the IVT).

Answer (score 1):

Take the steps below to rearrange the equation,

$$\sin\left(3x\right)+3\cos\left(5x\right)=0$$

$$\cos 5x+\cos(\frac\pi2+3x) =2\cos(\frac\pi2+3x)-2\cos 5x$$
$$\cos (x-\frac\pi4)\cos(4x+\frac\pi4) =2\sin(x-\frac\pi4)\sin(4x+\frac\pi4)$$
$$\tan(x-\frac\pi4)\tan(4x+\frac\pi4) =\frac12$$

The range of the LHS is $(-\infty,\infty)$, e.g. over $(-\frac{3\pi}{16}, \frac{\pi}{16})$. Thus, the equation has at least one root within $(-\frac{3\pi}{16}, \frac{\pi}{16})$ according to IVT. Due to the periodicity of the LHS, the equation has infinity number of roots.